# C programming - unexpected output

Tags: c, casting, output

I am not able to understand how the following code is working:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

 int i = 100;
 int *a = &i;
 float *f = (float *)a;

 (*f)++;

 printf("%d", *a); //getting some garbage value

}
```

'f' is pointing to the same memory location as that of 'a'. So, `(*f)++` should in turn increment the value of i to 101. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The behavior of this program heavily depends on how `float`s are represented in memory (most likely according to IEEE 754).

Comment: Firstly, the formal answer is that what you're doing is a violation of *strict aliasing rule* (that is, there is no `float` in the location `f` points to, so it's illegal to access `*f`). Thus the behvaiour of your program is undefiend, it can do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Floats and ints are stored with different binary representations. When you cast a `float` to an `int` or vice versa, the compiler takes care of this for you. But in your case, you're casting an `int*` to a `float*`, so you're modifying a float that has the wrong value, since the binary representation didn't get converted.

Comment: Thanks, just a small ques, If I replace `float *f = (float *)a;` with  `char *f = (char *)a;`, then the output is 101. Why isn't any problem arise in this case?

Comment: Because `char` is basically just a subset of `int` and is stored the same way, but `float` is completely different.